# atom-typescript does not compile and no manual compiler available

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I am starting with atom and have installed atom-typescript, this works as i am getting messages when typing into a .ts file but the changes are never compiled on save and I do not have an option to save manually, dependencies are also installed.
I have created a file called main.ts thinking the software would create a main.js file but this does not happen, I have then manually created a main.js file but the file remains empty.

In the atom-typescript/lib/tsconfig.json the option compileonsave is set to true.

I have uninstalled, re install etc but nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Looking further into the files and settings I have figured out that I can compile using the F6 key and this works but I am still unable to compileonsave